# Product of two triple products of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, determinant

Any hints/solutions to how I can show

$$ [ \mathbf{a,b,c}] [ \mathbf{u,v,w}]  = \begin{vmatrix}         \mathbf{a.u} & \mathbf{a.v} & \mathbf{a.w} \\         \mathbf{b.u} & \mathbf{b.v} & \mathbf{b.w} \\         \mathbf{c.u} & \mathbf{c.v} & \mathbf{c.w} \\         \end{vmatrix}$$

I would like to avoid fiddly manipulation of individual components at all costs if possible. I noted its trivial if one of $\mathbf{a,b,c}$ or $\mathbf{u,v,w}$ are planar so I assumed u,v,w can be written as a linear combination of a,b,c but couldn't see the followup. Expanding the determinant just got a load of terms too so not sure how that could help. I suppose I have missed something obvious.

Any thoughts would be appreciated. (also I am new to this site so sorry about any problems with my question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints**

$1.$ For any two $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$ and $B$ we have

$$\text{Det}(AB)=\text{Det}(A)\text{Det}(B)$$

$2.$ For three $3 \times 1$ vectors ${\bf{a}}$, ${\bf{b}}$ and ${\bf{c}}$ constructing the columns of a $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$ we know that

$$[ \mathbf{a,b,c}]=\text{Det}(A)$$